# Request passing as Null to an Endpoint in WSO2 EI 6.6

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I'm trying to pass the request as JSON to an endpoint but I get the incoming request null error, Please help me to sort this out.

```
<property expression="json-eval($.)" name="InputRequest" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <log level="custom">
            <property expression="$ctx:InputRequest" name="===VIN API Input Request==="/>
        </log>
        <property description="order_no" expression="json-eval($.order_no)" name="order_no" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <property description="chassis" expression="json-eval($.chassis)" name="chassis" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <property description="vin_number" expression="json-eval($.vin_number)" name="vin_number" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <header name="Authorization" scope="transport" value="Token 9e2ee7424134b4a87dd16dd80e4660143b1220f3"/>
        <header name="Content-Type" scope="transport" value="application/json"/>
        <payloadFactory description="Request Payload" media-type="json">
            <format>$1</format>
            <args>
                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:InputRequest"/>
            </args>
        </payloadFactory>
        <send description="Coms-Endpoint-Calling">
            <endpoint key="ComsEndpoint"/>
        </send>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is problem has been sorted out by using below mentioned property mediator after getting the Incoming Request.

```
<property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
```